# PCM Byte Array Addition

Tags: java, audio, pcm

I have a few raw PCM audio files. I can successfully read a stream of bytes from these files and play them through an audio playing mechanism which accepts PCM data as input.

When i read data from these files, i store it in byte[]. These tracks have the same size and are complementary in terms of sound (they sound good together). Therefore, I want to add several byte[] containing PCM data into a single byte[] of the same size, representing the final music.

I tried it in an easy thoughtless manner by simply doing it like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<finalbytes.length; i++)
{
   finalbytes[i] = (byte) (music1bytes[i] + music2bytes[i]);
}
```

It actually wasn't that bad. The final sound is indeed an addition of both tracks. The problem is, when a few tracks are added, sometimes in specific parts of the song, peaks of static noise can be heard. It is probably due to the addition resulting in non-clamped values or something, which I don't know how to solve.

So, how to add two or more byte arrays of PCM data?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the samples of these raw audio files are 8 bit signed.

What's happening is overflow.  If both samples add up to greater than 127 or less than -128 you won't get the correct result - you get integer overflow.

You could divide each resulting sample by 2:

```
finalbytes[i] = (byte) ((music1bytes[i] + music2bytes[i]) / 2);
```

This way, even if each audio file has a maximum sample value you will not get overflow.  Disadvantage is that resulting file might be a bit quiet.

Another option is to clip:

```
int sample = music1bytes[i] + music2bytes[i];
sample = Math.min(sample, Byte.MAX_VALUE);
sample = Math.max(sample, Byte.MIN_VALUE);
finalbytes[i] = (byte)sample;
```

If both audio sources are pretty loud then there might be a lot of clipping and it mightn't sound that great.

You could also try using [SoftMixingMixer](https://gervill.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/media/sound/SoftMixingMixer.html) from JavaSound and let it do the mixing for you.  Might actually be a lot more work this way since you'd need to define the audio format of the RAW audio files, but it likely will give the best sounding result.  With this option, you'll need to use `openStream(AudioFormat)` with the audio format of the output file and tell the mixer to play your 2 RAW audio files through lines.